# How can I customize existing user interfaces in WIX

Tags: c#, wix

I would like to add a custom user interface to my *.MSI created using Windows Installer XML. I am currently using the WIXUI_Advanced dialog set. I want to change the dialogs and remove some existing dialogs from it.

Can someone explain me the relationship between the dialogs and how to overwrite them with my custom code ? I have referred WIX documentation and ended up with a pile of errors while building the assembly.

Can someone explain me how these can be done with a working code example ?

Comment: Have you solved you problem?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for being in touch. My problem was I had used the same UI set name and same custom action properties. changing the names helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download wix source code and use WIXUI_Advanced dialog wxs file as a template.

For example - Remove the InstallDirDlg in Publish elements and save it to your solution.

Check this link for example: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

Comment: Once i add an existing template, this throws a pile of ID duplication errors. Is there something im doing wrong ?

Comment: Add you code, propably you indeed duplicated some things.